# Visual Studio could not communicate with Xcode

Tags: c#, xcode, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-mac, xcode10.2

Problem :

I'm trying to open an xib with Xcode through Visual Studio and give me this error. It started to appear since I did update in Visual Studio for Mac and in Xcode.

Visual Studio for Mac Version 8.0.1 (build 1)

Xcode Version 10.2

[This is the file I try to open in Xcode.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Co1eG.png)
[This is the error that appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4Wgg.png)

Comment: if you updated XCode, be sure to launch it and Accept any dialogs that it presents

Comment: @Jason Where do I accept these dialogs? After updating, Xcode no longer opens, it only opens through VS for Mac and gives an error.

Comment: they should just popup.  If XCode does not open at all it sounds like your installation is bad

Comment: @Jason But I downloaded the App Store, how is it possible that the download is not correct?

Comment: I do not work for Apple, so I have no idea.  Try rebooting your machine or doing some basic troubleshooting

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Yes, just check the solution here. I just delete the Xcode folder and run again in VS for Mac.

Comment: @RafaelSantos Great. Remember to post it as an answer and mark it. : )

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Has that worked out for you too? How do I do this?

Comment: @RafaelSantos It also works for me.You are right,I see the answer.Then you can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered this solution and it worked for me. I hope it works out for you.

Xcode can not find the solution to the problem because VS for Mac creates the project on another page, so I deleted the page that is generated by VS for Mac called Xcode and when starting up again it will already create a folder with the solution and run through Xcode.

[Delete Xcode folder and run again in VS for Mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DLFH.png)

Comment: Delete the "Xcode" folder within the "obj" folder, or delete "obj" entirely.

Comment: @Le-royStaines, I don’t remember now but I think you just need to delete the "obj" folder.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone has trouble opening big storyboards with VS for Mac, try opening a small xib first (right click on xib, then select open with Xcode interface builder). When Xcode is opened and VS is connected with it (VS watches the folder Xcode inside obj folder), browse the project in Xcode and select the big storyboard. I hope it will be useful to someone.